# Change VSCode sidebar (add icons) via theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to achieve something like sublime does, and if yes - how ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get icons by using this extension. Check it out:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons

> Installation
>
> Some people have reported that they cannot find the extension when
>   they insert the installation command:
>
> ext install vscode-icons
>
> If you're in the same position try this:
>
> ext install icons
>   or ext install "vscode-icons"
>
> Then go to File > Preferences > File Icon Theme > VSCode Icons. (Note
>   on OSX it is Code > Preferences > File Icon Theme > VSCode Icons.)

When version VSCode version 1.6.0 is released [icons will be supported in all this places](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11751#issuecomment-248634495):

- open editors view
- tabs
- title in editor when tabs are disabled
- search results
- problems
- quick open / editor pickers

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.5 this a few of the icon themes are built in: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_5

> **File Icon Themes**
>
> The File Explorer can now show file and folder icons.
>   To enable file icons, pick a File Icon Theme:
>
> Use the global menu File > Preferences > File Icon Theme (Code >
>   Preferences on Mac). Use the Preferences: File Icon Theme command in
>   the Command Palette (⇧⌘P). By default, no file icon set is configured
>   and the File Explorer doesn't render icons. Once a File Icon Theme is
>   selected, the choice will be persisted and used again on restarts of
>   VS Code. In this release, file icons are only shown in the File
>   Explorer, but we plan to use file icons in other places, for example
>   in Editor tabs.
>
> VS code ships with two icon themes and we expect the community to
>   contribute many more themes.

Comment: Please don't just post links to info. Extract the relevant info and embed it in your answer so the info is available even if the link breaks.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

No, not yet at least. The feature request tracking this is [#211](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/211).